# Loop Searches for String within a String from Two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, for-loop

I have two DataFrames of maintenance schedules from a dealership's repair shop for multiple car models:

1. The first DataFrame, titled "firstworkitems", is the all car models' first maintenance schedule consolidated into one df.
2. The second DataFrame, titled "lastworkitems", is all the car models' last maintenance schedule consolidated into one df.

The firstworkitems df looks like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVM4g.png

The lastworkitems df looks like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpWEW.png

As you can tell, the main difference between the two df's is that the title in the lastworkitems df has added text for contract changes (rccs) in the work.

What I am trying to do is create a for/if loop that will search the lastworkitem's Titles to see if the lastworkitems Title string contains a string from the firstworkitem's Titles, *based on the conditions that it has the be the same Car Model and same Work Item*, and in response, create two new columns in the lastworkitems to put the firstworkitem's Start and Finish Dates.

What I have done so far is not working, but if someone has a recommendation for an easier way, please let me know:

```
for x in range(len(lastworkitems)):
for y in range(len(firstworkitems)):
    if lastworkitems.loc[x, 'Car Model'] == firstworkitems.loc[y, 'Car Model']:
        if lastworkitems.loc[x, 'Work Item'] == firstworkitems.loc[y, 'Work Item']:
            lastworkitems.loc[x, 'First Start Date'] = np.where(lastworkitems.loc[x, 'Title'].str.contains(firstworkitems.loc[y, 'Title']), firstworkitems.loc[y, 'Start Date'], 0)
            lastworkitems.loc[x, 'First Finish Date'] = np.where(lastworkitems.loc[x, 'Title'].str.contains(firstworkitems.loc[y, 'Title']), firstworkitems.loc[y, 'Finish Date'], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use pd.merge() https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html to merge these two dataframes based on the work item (and car model if item is not unique). From there, you can use your np.where condition to search for appropriate text without having to loop

Comment: When I try to use workitems['Title Contains First'] = np.where(workitems['Title_x'].str.contains(workitems['Title_y']), 'True', 'False'), I get the error "Unhasable Type: 'Series'", how do I fix this?

Comment: That error is because Title_y is a series, not Title_y[index].

Try: 
df['new_col']=df.apply(lambda x: True if x['Title_y'] in x['Title_x'] else False, axis = 1)